# Find peak requests per minute, Windows Service-hosted WCF basicHttpBinding endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, logging

We have a Windows Service which hosts a WCF basicHttpBinding endpoint.

We would like to analyze incoming HTTP requests per minute to this endpoint at peak traffic times.

As of now the only logging we have is WCF Message Logging which is very verbose and cumbersome to parse.

How can we easily turn on some lightweight HTTP logging that can be used to analyze incoming HTTP requests per minute in retrospect?

Answer (score -1):

Use activity tracing and switch `logEntireMessage` off, you should then just have a header entry.

`logEntireMessage: By default, only the message header is logged but if we set it to true, the entire message including message header as well as body will be logged.`

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
              logEntireMessage="false"
              logMalformedMessages="false"
              logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
              logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
              maxMessagesToLog="3000"
              maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
   </diagnostics>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-Steps-to-Enable-Tracing-in-WCF

Then use Service Trace Viewer to examine the log file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the challenge is parsing these files, which are quite verbose even without logEntireMessage. How would we go from having e.g. a month's worth of data logged to answering the question regarding "peak requests per minute" for that month?

Comment: That is very specific. Only a couple of options really - the svclog is an xml file, you could create your own parser - I'm sure someone else out there has already done a lot of ground work on a project like this. Or host the WCF in IIS instead of as a service and use IIS logging for which there are many free and paid for tools which can get you specific information like that.

Comment: Or depending on how much traffic your service gets write a simple application event which you can then filter with system event viewer - this might not be ideal for very high traffic use.

Comment: I agree - but both of these answers involve quite a bit of changes to the system, which I am trying to avoid. Moving to IIS is not an option at the current time, and regarding the Application event + system event viewer suggestion, I'm trying to avoid writing custom code to perform the measurements. Also, I couldn't find any parser for messageLogging format to find requests per minute.

Comment: I think you're looking for a simple solution to a complicated problem and unfortunately the answer may just be it's not possible without considerable changes or effort. The only other thing I can really think of would be using 3rd party software to monitor the port that your service connects on and logging it at that level, http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html may be of some use or something like wireshark. Sorry I can't be of more help but as far as I'm aware there isn't really any other way to do this, I'd be really interested to see if anyone else can come up with a working solution.